# How do I inject a constant value in to the context in a BigCommerce theme?

Tags: bigcommerce

I need to create a template which has a fixed set of slides that are defined in the template. I'd like to render these slides based on an array of objects. How do I inject this array into the context?

```
{{inject "slides" [slide1, slide2, slide3,...]}}  //psuedo code, this doesn't actually work

<section class="onboardingSlider" data-slick='{
  "arrows": false,
  "mobileFirst": true,
  "slidesToShow": 1,
  "slidesToScroll": 1,
  "lazyLoad": "anticipated",
  "accessibility": false,
  "draggable": false,
  "infinite": false,
  "dots": false
}'> 
  {{#each slides}}
     <div class="js-slide">
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
     </div>
  {{/each}}
</section>
```

Appreciate the help on this, I'm new to BigCommerce!

Answer (score 1):

That is not what the "inject" helper is for: it injects a value in the JavaScript context, not in the template variables.

I believe what you are looking for, is called "Front Matter" - see https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/storefront-customization/using-front-matter

For example, see the beginning of templates/pages/product.html in the Cornerstone theme:

```
---
product:
    videos:
        limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_videos_count}}
    reviews:
        limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_reviews_count}}
    related_products:
        limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_related_products_count}}
    similar_by_views:
        limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_similar_by_views_count}}
---
```

You can use that to inject your array, and then reference that in template as the product template references "product.reviews" or "product.videos" from the example above.